# SyncHashtable this[Object key] does not use locking

Tags: c#-3.0, clr, base-class-library

I went through the implementation of `SyncHashtable` in defined in .Net framework BCL.

This class provides synchronized access to multiple readers and writers.

One of the methods is implemented as

```
public override Object this[Object key] {
            get {
                    return _table[key];
            }
            set {
                lock(_table.SyncRoot) {
                    _table[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

In my opinion the get method should also have a lock on Syncroot before accessing the object.

Consider the scenario :

Thread 1 :  Deleting keys from the `Hashtable`.

Thread 2 : Reading objects using keys.

If a context switch occurs in thread 2 while reading the object and if thread 1 deletes the object , then in such a case the read operation will fail or give inconsistent result.

Hence couldn't we implement this method like this

```
public override Object this[Object key] {
            get {
                 lock(_table.SyncRoot) 
                  {   
                   return _table[key];
                  }
            }
            set {
                lock(_table.SyncRoot) {
                    _table[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locking the `Hashtable` for reading is not necessary because that is already thread safe under these circumstances.

The documentation for `Hashtable` states:

> Hashtable is thread safe for use by multiple reader threads and a single writing thread.

By locking the write access, there is in effect only a single writer, and it is therefore unnecessary to lock reads.

Note that while this is true for `Hashtable`, it is *not* the case for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: I'm not calling the Hashtable threadsafe; I'm repeating the documentation in that it is thread safe for that specific scenario (multiple readers and a single writer). And that in turns makes SyncHashtable thread safe without needing to lock reads.

Comment: I just wanted to phrase it differently, which I now think might have been unnecessary. I deleted my original comment because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the thread-safety guarantees of the `Hashtable` I believe you are correct as the lock keyword is a monitor not a implicit reader-writer lock. This could definitely cause undesirable effects. However, given the situation as of today I'd look to the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610) for .NET 3.5, it ships with a System.Threading assembly that contains the new concurrent classes as part of the .NET 4.0. These classes are much better suited for dealing with multi-threaded access to collections.

Comment: As I said in my answer, Hashtable is thread-safe for multiple readers and a single writer, so it's not necessary to lock.

I would however agree with your suggestion to use a ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> instead, if possible.